# Reprojecting gif.gz raster to WGS84 using QGIS

Tags: raster, shapefile, overlay, modis

I am a steep learning curve into QGIS. I have a raster of global fire maps from the modis site: http://lance-modis.eosdis.nasa.gov/imagery/firemaps/firemap.2013221-2013230.8192x4096.gif.gz

How do I overlay this raster with a shapefile showing Global Administrative Boundaries (GAB)?

I have both files in WGS-84. However, I have noticed that the fire raster is offset south-east of the WGS84 GAB shapefile and the two do not overlay.

Comment: For me, the firemap aligns to Openstreetmap background, and Natural Earths World boundaries. How did you georeference the gif?

Comment: @AndreJoost after downloading the gif, I imported into Qgis directly and set its CRS as WGS84. I would like to load the gif into Qgis then load a shapefile of global administrative boundaries over it.

Answer (score 1):

The gif file does not have any georeference information (like geotiff has).

So you have to tell QGIS that the upper left corner is -180°E/90°N, upper right is +180°E/90°N, lower right is +180°E/-90°N and lower left corner is -180°E/-90°N.

The georeferencer is the tool to do this.

Without that information, QGIS treats the upper left corner as 0°E/0°N, beeing in the Atlantic in front of Nigeria, instead of Alaska. The lower right corner is treated as 8192°E -4096°N (one degree for every pixel), which makes no sense at all.

Once you have georeferenced your image, you can add shapefiles to the project, and both will fit.

---

**EDIT**

Georeferencing a transparent picture is a bit tricky, as you can not see the corners of the pictures.

But this is not a big problem: Just click in the edges of the screen at full extent, and enter the projected coordinates manually. After doing so for all cormers, you can edit the source coordinates in the GCP list manually to 0, 8192 and 4096 (the extent of the picture in pixels) respectively.

Comment: This is very helpful thanks, i have identified my problem. Now I should state am a QGIS novice, I've never georeferenced before and all the how-to helps on georeferencing I've found relate to georeferencing old maps and not rasters. I am having trouble getting the transformation setting as well as selecting points

Comment: EUREKA!!! thank you so much @AndreJoost, I was not selecting the points appropriately now I have my global administrative boundaries shapefile loaded over the fire map :) :)